# Apple Mach-O Linker Error in Parse Push Notification Framework

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, linker-errors, armv7

I have this Error:

```
ld: 91 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I searched for a solution for hours, but nothing really helped.

 Please help me, this is very annoying. I already tried a lot of things, nothing worked for me. 
 If you still need something, let me know!

This error appears, since I'm using Parse Push Notifications.

Thanks,
Jannes

Answer (score 0):

Pls follow these link: 
Add all required frameworks.

https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/ios/existing

Comment: Alle these frameworks are added... Still doesnt work

Comment: Also provide full error.Please check out in each viewcontroller, did you have import any .m file. If there than change it to .h file.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!
I just removed the Bolts framework and everything worked fine!
I don't know how Parse works without this but it does.